# Compute similarity with given weights for each different feature

Tags: python, recommender-system, similarity

I would like to find similar products based on the features.

I have:

- 3 categorical features (X1,X2,X3)
- 1 numerical (continuous) feature (X4)
- 1 date feature (X5)

Therefore, I want to give a **pre-defined** weight to each Xn feature in order to compute the similarity

**What would be the best approach?**

Answer (score 1):

To find similarity between products you need a metric by which to measure it, which you haven't specified.

for example, if you have items with only two features:
$ i_1 = [0.9,0.5] , i_2 = [0.9,0.3], i_3 = [0.5, 0.5] $
in one application similarity in the first feature may be more important so item 1 and item 2 would be more similar than item 1 and item 3, but in a different application, feature 2 may be more important so item 1 would be more similar to item 3 than item 2.

But generally speaking, you usually embed the categorical features into a continuous vector, you either bin and embed the continuous feature or directly transform it, and the date is usually used for feature engineering like holiday detection, weekday, month, etc.

Comment: Sorry for not addressing correctly my question. I wanted to know what are the most appropriate similarity measures for categorical, continuous and date types. I want to treat dates as a similarity features, if two products have the date closer they might be more similar.

Comment: It's application specific. Dates are problematic because there may be seasonality on different scales, holiday effects etc. Often the date is split to weekday, month, year and each of them is encoded using some method. One method would be to learn an embedding for each and then calculate the similarity on the learned vectors. Another, less general but also popular woud be to use cyclical encoding.